# What's the difference for a hosts file when deciding to use 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0?

Tags: ip, hosts-file

Since 0.0.0.0 matches any address and 127.0.0.1 is localhost, when deciding whether to choose one or the other to map unwanted IPs and domains in a hosts file, when is each best?

I read that in terms of hosts file, 0.0.0.0 maps to all ipv4 addresses and is therefore considered garbage and is to be thrown out. Why then does anyone use 127.0.0.1 instead provided that your system is hardly going to be used to host these domain names in lieu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

127.0.0.1 is localhost, by listening only to that address you can ensure that it is not at risk for being connected from outside the machine, which is good for security.

The ANY address 0.0.0.0 is used by the system to accept connections to any local address.

This does not mean that 0.0.0.0 matches any address, it is just a special case. When listening.

In terms of hosts file 0.0.0.0 makes no sense.

Comment: Never thought about this.  Presumably there is no way to represent 0.0.0.0 as a host (as distinct from a network) and as a network that means all hosts.

Comment: @davidgo 0.0.0.0 will always be a network address and never a host. This is IPv4 subnet "basics" pull out your favourite ipcalc tool and give it a shot.

Comment: Yup, that's what pretty much what I said said.

Comment: This is not the entire story. Although nonstandard, but in some operating systems, 0.0.0.0 is accepted as a connect destination and treated as "loopback" the same way as 127.0.0.1. Notably the various BSDs do this, and so does Linux (with its kernel source code having specific comments along the lines of "let's handle it the way BSD does"), I don't remember about Solaris but I did even try OpenVMS – so Windows might be the only mainstream OS that rejects 0.0.0.0 as invalid for connection.

Comment: Trying to connect to network address, (again use your favorite ipcalc tool) seems odd, just stop doing crazy stuff ... if you want something short for localhost, use `::1` If anything tries to use 0.0.0.0 or even accepts that, I would say bug.

Comment: @NiKiZe I see that 0.0.0.0 in a hosts file doesn't make sense and as such would be thrown out whereas loopback could respond under the right conditions. Is that not so?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do, 127.0.0.1 ::1 localhost is for hosting local instances, that is things you don't want the outside to reach, it is also what you connect to for any hosted resource, on the other hand any is what you host on to have it available for the outside, you can still connect to it on localhost.